# Наследование своего контроллера

Tags: php, codeigniter

При попытке унаследоваться от своего контроллера,вылезает ошибка.

> Message: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated

```
class Auth extends MY_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

}

include_once 'auth.php';

class Admin extends Auth{


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Где то в базовом классе есть код типа `$var =& new MyClass`, его надо заменить на `$var = new MyClass` (убрать & то есть). У вас валится на наследовании значит смотрите конструктор.

Comment: Не хотелось бы менять код в самом ядре!

Comment: @quaresma89 Вы хотите юзать древний код на новой версии языка при этом не менять код. Так не возможно. :) Либо измените код, либо оставьте старый пхп, либо обновите фреймворк.

Comment: Фреймворк последней версии,и php тоже

Comment: @quaresma89 ну так найдите строчку с ошибкой, потом уже можно что то обсуждать

Comment: Уже понизил версию php до 5.4.4 всеравно та же ошибка

Comment: @quaresma89 вам нужен php 5.2.x или ниже ИЛИ ci 2.1.4 или выше ИЛИ это где то в вашем коде, покажите строчку наконец

Comment: В том то и дело что  я не могу разобраться в какой строке кода ошибка!

Comment: Message: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated

Filename: pear/Auth.php

Line Number: 469

class Auth extends MY_Controller{

 public function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
 }
 
}

Comment: @quaresma89 найдите строчку типа $a =& new A. Базовые конструкторы смотрите.

Comment: Уже из всех системных классов убрал ссылки,всеравно ошибка осталась.В основном такие записи в базовых конструктарах $CI = & get_instance() поубирал и тут везде ссылки и всеравно ничего!

Comment: Решил проблему require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/Auth.php';